# разница между width="50px" и style="width: 50px;"

Tags: html

В чем разница между заданием размеров (`width`, `height`) объекта в виде `width="50px"` и `style="width:50px;"`?

Выражается в том, что *canvas*, созданный с размерами в виде `width="50px" heght="50px"` заливается командой

```
<context_canvas'a>.fillRect ( 0 , 0 , 50 , 50 ) ;
```

корректно, а в виде `style="width:50px;height:50px;"` только частично.

Или, все-таки, эти объявления параметров не взаимозаменяемы?

вот, собственно, код:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Документ Без Имени</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">  

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
      var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");  
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  
      ctx.fillRect ( 0 , 0 , 200 , 30 ) ;
});   
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!--
  <canvas id="myCanvas"
          style="height: 30px;
                 width: 200px;
                ">
  </canvas> 
-->                 
  <canvas id="myCanvas"
          height="30"  
          width="200">
  </canvas>  

</body>
</html>
```

первый canvas заливается криво, а второй - нормально...

Comment: `50px` — неправильное значение для атрибута width. Правильное — `50`.

Comment: да, это я машинально (привык к CSS) написал "width=50px", в коде, конечно, без "px"! . Но вопрос не в этом. Почему canvas'ы  с разными типами установки размеров (через style и без) заливаются fillRect'ом по-разному???

Answer (score 1):

HTML-атрибут `width` доступен не для всех тегов. CSS в этом плане более гибкий.

На банальном примере: `<div width="50"></div>` и `<div style="width: 50px"></div>`. В первом случае у div будет стандартная ширина в 100%, во втором - 50px. HTML атрибуты описаны в спецификации [W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/div).